# How to implement JWT verification check properly in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm currently building a simple admin dashboard. Using JWT to authenticate and authorise the user.

So far I've implemented the login and store the JWT inside a cookie. Everything works fine but what I'm having issues with is when the JWT is expired.

Whenever the JWT is expired I want the website to redirect the user to the login page again when the user is trying to navigate the website.

Whenever the JWT is expired and I refresh the page the website redirects the user to the login page, but when I'm navigating the website via the navigation menu no redirect to login is done.

```
<Link prefetch={false} href="/admin/clubs/view" className="flex items-center gap-x-3.5 py-2 px-2.5 text-sm text-slate-700 rounded-md hover:bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-slate-400 dark:hover:text-slate-300">
    View clubs
 </Link>
```

The middleware config:

```
export const config = {
  matcher: ['/admin', '/admin/:path*'],
}
```

AFAIK there's some magic with the Link component from NextJS and middleware, where middleware is not ran when the prefetch is set to true. But I've now set it to false and it still does not run the middleware.

Comment: Why not put some sort of header include file that checks for the cookie and when it isn't there, redirect them  to the page you want (login).

Comment: @easleyfixed Can you elaborate a bit more? I'm new to FE. But the implementation I want (which could likely be wrong) is that when the user is navigating between the pages inside the admin dashboard the middleware should be run and check whether the token is expired, is this the wrong approach?

Comment: If its wrong then I'm in trouble cause that is how I do it, but I use a different language and I use session objects instead of cookies.  Unfortunately due to this, I can't provide more than concept.

Comment: @easleyfixed Ok, thanks for the input tho. My explanation might be a bit bad so I'll try to give it another shot. When the user signs in I store the JWT inside a cookie. When the user is navigating the website and the token is expired the user should be redirected to the login page. Now there's no redirect to the login page if the JWT is expired, only when the page is refreshed. I believe this is due to the Link component and how NextJS handles when Middleware is being run. I thought by adding the prefetch option to the Link component would solve the problem but it didn't

Comment: Oh I think I see what your problem is. You are saying that the script is acting non-bidirectional, as in, it only updates when you submit the data?  So of course it would only know to navigate to the logout once the next action tried to happen and would instead be sent to login page.    I can only think that you would have to build some sort of javascript timer that counts down and is run on the client side to track the session then have it automatically redirect when the timeout happens.